# How do I add a system.core.dll reference to my project in xamarin studio/monodevelop

Tags: c#, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to use `System.Linq` because it has an 'Unknown resolve error'. I've done a bit of looking around on how to do this and all I can find is people saying that it needs to be added or that they added it. I'm wondering how to add it to my project so that I can use the '.ToList' function.

Comment: I'd expect you to be able to add it just like any other framework assembly reference. Does it not appear as an option?

Comment: Do you mean like ’using System. Core;’ it wasn't an option and it errored at me when I typed it anyway.  If you mean as an option somewhere in the solution options then no to that as well as best as I could discover.  I know its possible because I saw a guy in a forum ask about ’linq’ not working and got directed to add it.  Ill double check everything again in the morning

Comment: No, that's a using directive for a namespace. You need to add an assembly reference in the project. It's not something you do in source code - it's a project option.

Comment: That worked. I just wasn't familiar with how/where to do that in xamarin thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing a traditional iOS or Android project with Xamarin Studio, by default a reference to System.Core should already be added.

However, if you're creating a PCL you will see a reference to it, but it will be red in the References folder. This is because PCLs are not fully supported yet. There is a work around though.

You can copy the Core DLL from your Mono install and reference it in your PCL project. I was able to find this PCL on my Mac here:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.0.10/lib/mono/4.0 - mscorlib.dll

I usually have a folder called "DLLs" inside my project folder that I put these type of DLLs and reference.

Hopefully in the near future we won't have to mess with hacks like this with PCLs.

Comment: This also worked but in the end I found the reference assembly section. Thanks though.