# Xamarin / Mono can't find System.Core

Tags: c#, mono, nunit, xamarin

I have a test project under Xamarin that when I try to run it it tells me it can't load System.Core though from the screen shot it is clear that System.Core is one of the references.

What Might be the error here?

(open the image in a new tab to see it in full detail)

[image: xamarin test error]

It seems the problem is with my primary project not the test project. When
I looked at all the references they were red. So I deleted them and tried
to add them again but there are no references to add. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: I think I created the project as PCL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747774/how-do-i-add-a-system-core-dll-reference-to-my-project-in-xamarin-studio-monodev suggests what the problem is. It is a Xamarin bug that they just don't support PCL. Ok but how to un PCL my library?

Answer (score 2):

The following edits to the .csproj file fixed the problem

```
--- a/SketchSolveC#/SketchSolveC#.csproj
+++ b/SketchSolveC#/SketchSolveC#.csproj
@@ -6,12 +6,9 @@
     <ProductVersion>12.0.0</ProductVersion>
     <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
     <ProjectGuid>{46D849FA-8E4B-4656-B494-290697EBD9EC}</ProjectGuid>
-    <ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
     <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
     <RootNamespace>SketchSolveC</RootNamespace>
     <AssemblyName>SketchSolveC#</AssemblyName>
-    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile1</TargetFrameworkProfile>
-    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
     <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
@@ -30,15 +27,13 @@
     <ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
-    <Reference Include="System" />
-    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
-    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
-  </ItemGroup>
-  <ItemGroup>
     <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
     <Compile Include="SketchSolve.cs" />
+    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
+    <Reference Include="System.Data.Linq" />
+    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
+    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
   </ItemGroup>
-  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Portable\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" />
   <ProjectExtensions>
     <MonoDevelop>
       <Properties>
@@ -49,4 +44,4 @@
       </Properties>
     </MonoDevelop>
   </ProjectExtensions>
-</Project>
\ No newline at end of file
+</Project>
```