# Unknown resolve error with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xamarin-studio

I'm on Xamarin Studio and I'm trying to get what the user will input and translate it with the first char in upper Case, but `text.First()` give me `Unknown resolve error`. In the same file I'm already using Linq expression successfully.

```
public void TextChanged(String text)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (text))
        text = text.First().ToString().ToUpper() + text.Substring(1); //Unknown resolve error
}
```

Comment: First() should give the first character.. Ex: "Pippo" will give "p".
Yeah i know its immutable but in the method I'll do something else.

Comment: It looks like a [Xamarin intellisense type issue](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16061/unknown-resolve-error-in-library) - does your code compile?

Comment: @StuartLC Compiling give: `Error CS0411: The type arguments for method ``System.Linq.Queryable.First<TSource>(this System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly (CS0411) (App)`

Comment: You are doing check for `null`, there exists [another way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3878820/1997232) to get first character: `text[0]`.

Comment: Yeah I know but this should work.. I'd like to know why there is this problem.

Comment: @DQuaglio Your problem is different., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747774/how-do-i-add-a-system-core-dll-reference-to-my-project-in-xamarin-studio-monodev

Comment: @Thirisangu I don't think, I'm already using in the same file a Linq expression. Also I already have the reference added by default.

Comment: @DQuaglio what I can't get is the fact that `System.Linq.IQueryable` is used and not `System.Linq.IEnumerable`  is used. A string implements `IEnumerable` not `IQueryable`. Honestly, quite weird.

Comment: Yeah it is, I tried in another project and this line of code works...Really weird.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
text = Char.ToUpper(text.First())+text.Substring(1);
```

Comment: Not working, same error... It does not recognize the Linq methods.

Comment: Have you included the namespace `System.Linq`?

Comment: Yes, in the same file in another method I already used another Linq expression succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

***On aspx page***

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>enter code here
            Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text=""/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Age:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" Text="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20130526/json2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=btnSubmit]").click(function () {
            var obj = {};
            obj.name = $.trim($("[id*=txtName]").val());
            obj.age = $.trim($("[id*=txtAge]").val());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "FirstUpper.aspx/SendParameters",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r.d);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</form>
```

on cs page

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string SendParameters(string name, int age)
    {

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            name = name.First().ToString().ToUpper() + name.Substring(1);

        return string.Format("Name: {0}{2}Age: {1}", name, age, Environment.NewLine);

    }

}
```